Mac miniをicloud.comから間違えてデータ消去してしまった
Mac miniのアクティベーション解除を行うつもりが、操作を間違えてしまい、
icloud.comからデータの中身を遠隔消去してしまいました。
Mac miniを起動させると、Appleのアカウントを聞かれ、認証を行うと、アクティーベートは成功しましたが、
（対象のディスクが見つからず）OSの再インストールができない状況です。
ディスクユーティリティを起動すると
disk0s1が525MB、disc0s2が5.37GBしか無く、これはおそらくベースのOS領域ということでしょうか。
消去しようとするとベース領域のため消去は失敗しますし、リストアもできません。FirstAidはうまく行っています。
OSを再インストールしようとすると、対象のディスクが表示されないため、何もできない状況です。
とくにディスクが壊れたわけではないと思うので、何とか復旧させる方法はないでしょうか？
